# Titanium appcelerator: FileUriExposedException - How to use Content Provider?

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I try to open a local pdf but it won't open because of this exception: `android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/appid/1438-938X_2015_07/0.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`

I think I need to use a content provider, but how can I get the `content://` path in appcelerator?

Comment: Could you share what Titanium SDK version and Android API level you are using?

Comment: I am using Ti SDk 6.0.4.GA and Android target SDK 25. But I fixed it today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I was able to fix my issue.I didn't have to use a content provider.
I was using this code to create an Intent:

```
            Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action: Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
            type: 'application/pdf',
            data: pdfPath
        }));
```

No I am using this code:

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action : Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
            type : "application/pdf",
            data: pdfPath
        }); 


        var open = Ti.Android.createIntentChooser(intent, L('open_intent'));
        Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(open);
```

I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem!

Comment: This solution does not work for Ti SDK 6.2.2 and Android target SDK 25 running on an Android 7+.

Answer (score 0):

There was a fix in Ti SDK 6.3.0 that fixed this.